# Removing a folder from File Explorer that no longer exists on the file system

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, ntfs

I uninstalled an application using the product's official MSI package, it worked as expected but seems to have left a 'phantom' folder behind which is blocking my next installation.

I'm 99% sure I can resolve this issue by simply restarting the host, but in the interest of finding a smoother solution (let's just pretend this is a production server that cannot be swiftly restarted) I thought I would provide some info here and see what comes to light.

Some notes:

1. All commands were run in an elevated prompt.
2. My account is a member of the Local Administrators group.

*The folder path contains Personally Identifiable Information and has therefore been redacted.*

[Attempting to DELETE the folder using PowerShell (elevated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5lMl.png)

- `[Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException`
- `Cannot find path 'C:\ProgramData\FOLDER' because it does not exist`
- `PermissionDenied: (C:\ProgramData\FOLDER:String)`
- `[Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException`

[Attempting to ACCESS the folder using File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAOS4.png)

- `C:\ProgramData\Folder is not accessible`

[Attempted to DELETE the folder using File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JNLZ.png)

- The delete action prompts for elevation.
- Upon elevating, it fails with this message.

[Viewing the Security tab of the folders properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zopn.png)

- I did have access to this folder prior to the uninstallation. I don't think this matters, as we're looking at the properties of a folder that doesn't actually exist. I am unable to give myself access or claim ownership of this folder, all actions fail.

**What has caused this folder to remain in File Explorer when it no longer exists, and what methods are available to 'nuke' the folder (with exception to restarting the OS)?**

*For those (quite rightly) thinking of flagging this as a duplicate, none of these worked:
 1. [How do I delete a file that Windows says doesn't exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/1277529/how-do-i-delete-a-file-that-windows-says-doesnt-exist)
 2. [Cannot Delete Item "Could Not Find This Item" issue](https://superuser.com/questions/28912/cannot-delete-item-could-not-find-this-item-issue)
 3. [How to fix a directory that is there but doesn't exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/1008624/how-to-fix-a-directory-that-is-there-but-doesnt-exist/1009012)
 4. About 6 other solutions also tried*

Comment: Have you tried just restarting explorer? Note also that the uninstaller may have used an option to delete files/folders on the next boot.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, yes I did try killing and restarting explorer - good suggestion though. I happen to have the MSI build source for this installer, the folder is deleted on 'uninstall': `<util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="ProgramDataDirectory" />`

Comment: Run "chkdsk" with no switches in command prompt, it may fix it, no switches means read only no repair, but I have had it fix issues like this without the F or R.

Comment: In addition to running chkdsk reboot your system. I had a case where the reboot was required to finally make a directory disappear the MSI deinstaller of LibreOffice had left over (that directory was also giving permission errors despite the account deleting it was local admin).

Comment: I did end up rebooting the host, I was hoping there would be a smoother option. I'm glad it was just my home PC and not a production server in the office!