# PDF with long file name won't delete

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a pdf file on my desktop with a long file name that won't delete.  I have researched and tried many solutions, but it will not delete.  There is no .pfd at the end of the file name.  The filename is
APznzab4iM5Qia7KFKzl9H2pzr7o6aBeLbGEYDWkbuYbOMC0kCEhp7vJY8-75if8WCT-0gYtJf6oM5SDBgniy5D4_iRFhODCFe99n--JbwUqA9IbgLpld0OK7rY0PC5zylIHRA1MIPf3QfL3eHfb--NLZXO0QxOAyHNs5GG4wHtN44CTH5MfAXuo-sK3c34L7rdwHbTnRgnA9bZY_OIOwkB8qHUNEb1ZL0L1rn7hWmdAdWSuKHTJcEVQztT

Comment: Is this windows

Comment: Try my solution here  https://superuser.com/questions/1008624/how-to-fix-a-directory-that-is-there-but-doesnt-exist/1009012#1009012  It is for a directory, but it will work for files too.

Comment: if it's Windows then there are already so many duplicates: https://superuser.com/q/755298/241386, https://superuser.com/q/45697/241386, https://superuser.com/q/78434/241386 ...

Comment: Not to brag, but almost everyone I've spoken seems to find the method I use to be by far the easiest. See the duplicate.

Comment: You can also get, keep, and use Unlocker 1.92 (Major Geeks). Funky software but I have it and it deletes any file I wish (so I use great care).